# terra::buffer() questionable functionality

Tags: r, buffer, terra

When I try to create a circular polygon (using terra::buffer) to obtain a polygon with a specified area, the result is far from expected.

The code below illustrates the problem. Running R 4.2.2 on Windows (x86_64=w64-mingw32), using terra_1.7-3

Thanks.

I want to produce a circular polygon with a specified area. This is conceptually simple since the radius (r) is equal to the square-root of the Area (A) over Pi. r=sqrt(A/pi)

I then use the terra::buffer with DIST set as the computed radius to create the circular polygon, centered on a centroid point of a polygon from which I initially took the desired area. When I compute the terra::expanse() of this new circular polygon, it is nowhere near the desired area. Is this a bug or am I completely missing something? The desired area is ~1.7 larger than for the buffered circle.

```
library(terra)

# CONTROL WHICH POLYGON TO PROCESS WITHIN SpatVect
whichpoly <- 8

# SET GRAPHICAL ENVIRONMENT
plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

# IMPORT DEMO SHAPEFILE AND PROJECT PROPERLY
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
test <- project(v, "EPSG:2150")

# PRODUCE STARTING MAP
plot(test, col="LightGrey", alpha=0.3)
plot(test[whichpoly], col="LightGreen", alpha=0.7, add=TRUE)
plot(centroids(test), add=TRUE)
plot(centroids(test[whichpoly]), col="Red", add=TRUE)
title(paste("Full Map: Centroids & Circle [", whichpoly, "]", sep=""))

# RATHER THAN BUILD A CIRCLE WITH THE EXTENT OF THE SHAPE, MATCH THE AREA TO THE SHAPE - NOT WORKING
# RADIUS OF A CIRCLE WITH SAME AREA AS SHAPE
# RADIUS = SQUARE-ROOT(AREA/PI)
radius2 <- sqrt(expanse(test[whichpoly])/pi)
buff2 <- buffer(centroids(test[whichpoly]), radius2)
plot(test[whichpoly])
plot(buff2, add=TRUE, col="cornflowerblue", alpha=0.5)

# AREAS
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly])
terra::expanse(buff2)
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly]) / terra::expanse(buff2)
```

Comment: The data are planar and while the area will vary based on input; the "size" of any circle is not an issue in this case.

Comment: The code and data is provided above. It pulls the data from the demo that is provided with the package (terra) and is available when you run the code as provided. Everything is there. I even have the code illustrate the result and it provides the areas and the difference ratio for them.

Comment: Ah, thank you Tarmo. I missed that.

Comment: I think you just need `transform = FALSE` inside `extent`. This gives you values that agree within half a percent

Comment: Can you share a few lines of the `test` object so we can develop a solution more easily?  
  `dput(test)`

Comment: @Ben the example is fully reproducible - it's a built-in data set

Comment: Sorry folks,   my bad

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy vanishes if you use `transform = FALSE` inside `extent`

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.3

whichpoly <- 8

plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
test <- project(v, "EPSG:2150")

plot(test, col="LightGrey", alpha=0.3)
plot(test[whichpoly], col="LightGreen", alpha=0.7, add=TRUE)
plot(centroids(test), add=TRUE)
plot(centroids(test[whichpoly]), col="Red", add=TRUE)
title(paste("Full Map: Centroids & Circle [", whichpoly, "]", sep=""))

radius2 <- sqrt(expanse(test[whichpoly], transform = FALSE)/pi)
buff2 <- buffer(centroids(test[whichpoly]), radius2)
plot(test[whichpoly])
plot(buff2, add=TRUE, col="cornflowerblue", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

```r
# AREAS
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly], transform = FALSE)
#> [1] 360211556
terra::expanse(buff2, transform = FALSE)
#> [1] 358732072
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly]) / terra::expanse(buff2)
#> [1] 1.004125
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The reason behind the discrepancies is that the `expanse` function with `transform=TRUE` is computing the most exact area of the polygons because it uses the actual lat/long instead of the projected coordinates. However, the `buffer` function computes the distances (which becomes an area) using the projected coordinates of the map. Using the `transform=FALSE` makes the two functions go from one to the other more seamlessly but it should be kept in mind that the result with `transform=FALSE` introduces error. Another point is the buffer circle is not a completely perfect circle but has edges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the used CRS ([EPSG:2150](https://epsg.io/2150)) does not play well with that specific Shapefile (*lux.shp*, Luxembourg), it doesn't just get areas wrong (`AREA` attribute for 8th polygon, Grevenmacher, is 210 km^2) but also switches easting / northing and ends up having values out of UTM range. For projected CRS we could use `+proj=utm +zone=31` as in the example bellow, though `?terra::expanse` actually advises not to use planar coordinates for vectors:

> For vector data, the best way to compute area is to use the longitude/latitude CRS. This is contrary to (erroneous) popular belief that suggest that you should use a planar coordinate reference system. This is done automatically, if `transform=TRUE.`

Long/lat SpatVector would also fine for `terra::buffer()`

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.39

library(sf)
library(mapview)

whichpoly <- 8

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
test <- project(v, "+proj=utm +zone=31")

s <- st_as_sf(v)
mapviewOptions(basemaps = "CartoDB.Positron")
mapview(s, col.regions = "LightGreen") + 
  mapview(st_centroid(s)) + 
  mapview(st_centroid(s)[whichpoly,], col.regions = "red", alpha = 1)
```

[image]

```r
radius2 <- sqrt(expanse(test[whichpoly])/pi)
buff2 <- buffer(centroids(test[whichpoly]), radius2)
plot(test[whichpoly])
plot(buff2, add=TRUE, col="cornflowerblue", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

```r
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly])
#> [1] 210354494
terra::expanse(buff2)
#> [1] 209358272
terra::expanse(test[whichpoly]) / terra::expanse(buff2)
#> [1] 1.004758
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, this indeed looks like the best way forward; thank you. I will switch to a lat/long projection and simply use that; then all of the functions play nicely together. As another respondent mentioned, the error is then only about 0.4%.

Comment: @TarmoRemmel, the main point I tried to make was selecting projected CRS that's not out of bounds for that specific area -- UTM zone 17 (EPSG:2150) would be fine*  for some areas in US and Canada, but when applied to European countries as in this case, one should be prepared for some funky results. Zones - https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm . * - perhaps avoid EPSG:2150, this one seems to be deprecated, but there are plenty of other coordinate systems based on the same UTM zone. And just to be clear, both current answers here use projected coordinates.